# Dynamically adding scene to tab JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tabs, tabcontrol

this is easily achievable in C# but I'm having problems replicating it with JavaFX.

I'm writing a TDI program (tabbed document interface), so I have a bunch of different tools in fxml files (rich text editors, etc) that I'd like to add as tabs in the main scene. Each "tool" is, of course, its own scene right now. I want the main scene to host a tab control that will contain all the different tools.

What would be a way to do this with JavaFX?

Comment: You could use **Sub**Scenes but to me it seems like designing those tools as `Scene`s and not as `Node`s was the wrong choice.

Comment: @fabian I looked into redoing them as nodes. The problem is that there are a lot of components so designing them visually is absolutely ideal (with the scene builder). Adding each component dynamically will be a headache. Is there a way to design nodes (like a pane) visually?

Comment: ????? SceneBuilder is used to create nodes (or node structures, which is what i meant in my comment). The last time i tried SceneBuilder wouldn't let me place anything, but nodes in the fxml file or it would fail to open a fxml file. If by scene you mean anything that extends `Node` i don't really see the problem with placing them in `Tab`s...

Comment: The best way to go about this is to take the roots of each scene and add them to the tabs. Easiest way i know! It shouldnt make a difference in terms of your program. Hope this works.